# Proof involving Cyclic group, generator and GCD

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Theorem:
$$\left\langle a^k \right\rangle = \left\langle a^{\gcd(n,k)}\right\rangle$$
Let G be a group and $$ a \in G$$ such that $$|a|=n$$
Then:

$$\left\langle a^k \right\rangle = \left\langle a^{\gcd(n,k)}\right\rangle$$

The proof begins by letting d = gcd(n,k) such that d is a divisor of k so there exists an integer r such that k = dr. 
So, $$a^k=(a^d)^r$$.

$$\left\langle a^k \right\rangle \subseteq \left\langle a^{\gcd(n,k)}\right\rangle$$

I've spent a very long time on understanding this proof but found it to be obscure. I suspect there are some gaps in my understanding. If someone could show me the light I'll be really glad.
I do not understand why the exponent r on a 'vanishes'.

Secondly, how does $$a^k\in \left\langle a^d\right\rangle$$ follows?

Thirdly, where does closure plays a role?

Comment: It has been edited but the nature of my question remains unchanged.

Comment: Do you know Bézout's theorem that if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, then there exists an integer $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1 \pmod n$?

Comment: With $|a|$, do you mean the order of $a$ with respect to the group $G$ ?

Comment: @Peter I have. If it were $$a^k=a^r$$, I would have no problem since I can exploit the division algorithm. and show that $$a^k$$ is in the cyclic group generated by the element.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: @fkraiem I don't but I do know that if the gcd of two non-zero integers is 1, then the 2 integers are relatively prime to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Given an element $a$ of a group $G$, $\langle a\rangle$ is by definition *the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $a$*. This means in particular that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $a$, then $\langle a\rangle \subseteq H$.

Here, you want to prove two statements of this form (for ease of notation, I let $d = \gcd(n,k)$):

1. You want to prove that $\langle a^k\rangle \subseteq \langle a^d\rangle$. From the preceeding discussion, this is the same thing as proving that $a^k \in \langle a^d\rangle$, which in turn means that there is some $e$ such that $a^k = \left(a^d\right)^e$.
2. Conversely, you want to prove that $\langle a^d\rangle \subseteq \langle a^k\rangle$, this is the same thing as $a^d \in \langle a^k\rangle$.

The first one is easy: $d$ is by definition a divisor of $k$, so there exists an integer $e$ such that $k = de$. But then $\left(a^d\right)^e = a^{de} = a^k$ so $a^k \in \langle a^d\rangle$.

For the second one, you have to know that if $\gcd(n,k) = d$, then there exists an integer $\ell$ such that $k\ell \equiv d\pmod n$, meaning that there exists an integer $m$ such that $k\ell = d + mn$. Then
$$\left(a^k\right)^\ell = a^{k\ell} = a^{d+mn} = a^da^{mn} = a^d\underbrace{\left(a^n\right)}_{=1}{}^m = a^d,$$
so $a^d \in \langle a^k\rangle$.

Comment: I apologise but this is very frustrating especially having stayed awake for more than 14 hrs.
Given $$a^k$$, I know that by the division algo, we have $$a^k=a^(qn+r)=(a^n)^q=ea^r=a^r$$ And since r is between 0 and n, we have $$a^k$$ lying in the group generated by the element a.

Comment: But how is $$a^k=(a^d)^e$$?

Comment: You might really have to spell it out.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Since $k = de$, certainly $a^k = a^{de} = \left(a^d\right)^e$, no?

Comment: shouldn't it be k=dr? Assuming you were using a different form, why is r = e in this case?

Comment: What's $r$? There is no $r$ in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the converse part

since $d=gcd(n,k)$ and therefore from $euclidian~ algorithem$ there exists

integers $s~\&~t$ such that

$ns+kt=d$

This will imply that  $a^d=a^{ns+kt}$

$\implies a^d=(a^n)^s (a^k)^t$

$\implies a^d=(a^k)^t$ since $|a|=n$

$\implies a^d \in <a^k>$

So combining equalities you'll get required thing

Comment: This does not answer my problem.
My issue is still with 
1) how the last sentence followed from the second last.
2)closure

Comment: I am not able to know where you have confusion. Specify clearly

Comment: 1)How does $$\left.a^k\text{=(}a^d)^r\text{$\to $ }a^k\in \langle a^d\right\rangle$$
2)How does $$\left\langle a^k\text{$\rangle \backslash \backslash $subset$\langle $}a^{\gcd
   (n,k)}\right\rangle$$ follows from closure?

Comment: This is basic cyclic group's result.